# Index of nth biggest item in Python list

Tags: python, list

I can't edit or sort the list. How can I get that index?

Comment: Is this homework? "can't edit or sort the list" seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: You need to ask an actual question. Nothing you posted actually is a question.

Comment: no, im implementing a neural network, and i cant get a nice way for parsing the outputs.. as i am new to python :\

Comment: So why can't you sort the list? Whatever solution you come up with is going to involve *some kind* of ordering operation...

Comment: i have this "move = dirs[res.index(max(res))]" for the maximum output, but sometimes the choosen output cant be used (pacman move) and i need to get the secong bigger result on list

Comment: if i sort the list i lose the original index, which represents the pacman move "dirs = [Directions.NORTH, Directions.SOUTH, Directions.EAST, Directions.WEST, Directions.STOP]"

Comment: Everything can solved by another level of indirection, right? Just sort another list which references the original one. Or use a pair/tuple/or whatever it's called in python. Or loop through a second time if it's really only 5 items in the list? But you really do need to ask a question here or else nobody knows what to answer.

Comment: Please, could someone with enough rights correct 'pyhton' in the title?. It hurts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [heapq](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) module provides a [nlargest](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) function that efficiently finds the n largest elements of a list:

```
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>> items = [100, 300, 200, 400]
>>> indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> nlargest(2, indexes, key=lambda i: items[i])
[3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got is already O(n) in complexity (`max` is O(n), as is `index()`, IIRC). So while you *could* technically just remove the largest if it's not appropriate and try again, you're starting to get into bubblesort territory in terms of big-O. How many items are typically on the list?

One option is [QuickSelect](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~stbird/Tutorials/QuickSelect.html), which is basically a reduced QuickSort, but honestly just sorting the list up front is not going to be much slower than what you've got already.

You can use the [sorted()](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#SortingBasics) function to return a new sorted list if you don't want to change the ordering of the original list.

Comment: @Jim Lewis: yes, that's why I pointed to QuickSelect, which is O(n). I didn't actually know python had an nlargest function already, which sth pointed out... shows my newbness with python :) My point was (if nlargest didn't exist), sorting the list (O(nlogn)) is not going to be much worse than the 2xO(n) that he was already doing...